# POSIX shared memory + directories

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory

The OS I'm working on (IBM CNK, which is not Linux, but somewhat POSIX-compliant) doesn't allow me to simply create a new file or directory in /dev/shm using fopen() or mkdir(), respectively. It looks like I have to use shm_open() to get a file descriptor and then fdopen() to use the shared region for file I/O.

- Do I need to set the size of the shared region using ftruncate(), or does it grow automatically? I've tried it and I can simply fprintf into the region and it works, but is it safe?
  The manpage only says:

  > A new shared memory object initially has zero length  —  the
  >                    size of the object can be set using ftruncate(2).  The newly
  >                   allocated bytes of a shared memory object are  automatically
  >                 initialized to 0.
- Do I want to mmap() the region? I simply want to have a directory with files in it in memory.
- How would I create a new directory in /dev/shm? Is this "work with /dev/shm as if it was a normal filesystem" a new thing? Are directories in /dev/shm maybe not standard?

Comment: > Recent 2.6 Linux kernel builds have started to offer /dev/shm as shared memory in the form of a RAM disk, more specifically as a world-writable[clarification needed] directory that is stored in memory with a defined limit in /etc/default/tmpfs. /dev/shm support is completely optional within the kernel configuration file. It is included by default in both Fedora and Ubuntu distributions.


Aha ...

Comment: y: He wrote that he is NOT using Linux...

Comment: OP and niscy are the same person :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your OS provide a full-featured `mmap` ? Do you only need the shared memory area in relatives, i.e. processes that you `fork`ed off ? If those two conditions are met you don't need any files at all, just use mmap:

```
char *shm_area;
shm_area = mmap(NULL, mySHMsize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, 0, 0);

if (fork() == 0) {
  // Child, can access shm_area.
} else {
  // Parent, can access shm_area.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of IBM CNK before… but let's make some generalizations from POSIX/SUS.

It's not portable to `mmap` beyond the end of a file.  You should call `ftruncate` to set the end of the file before mapping it.

The presence of `/dev/shm` is purely an implementation detail of `shm_open`.  It would be POSIX-compliant to have no `/dev/shm` and implement `shm_open` in some other way.  On Linux, `/dev/shm` happens to be a normal (though memory-backed) filesystem, but you can't portably expect `/dev/shm` to act filesystem-like, or even exist.

Comment: FYI: CNK = Compute Node Kernel. Runs on the BlueGene/P backend nodes.